# Printing to a file while conducting n simulations for a program (in C)

Tags: c, file-io

I am conducting *n* simulations using a program and albeit everything being correct, there is only one mistake which I am able to see in the output files.

I am printing the outputs of the program to a `csv` file.

I check the file before I print to it to get it's size which if it is 0, I print the headers. Here is the function which does the same:

```
void Data_Output(FILE *fp, int node_num, int agg_num, int cnode, int sysdelay, int bwdth_reqt)
{
    struct stat buf;
    int fd = fileno(fp);
    fstat(fd, &buf);

    //Debug Statement
    fprintf(stderr,"%d-",buf.st_size);

    if (!buf.st_size) {
        // Writing Headers
        fprintf(fp,"Tot_Nodes_Num,Agg_Nodes_Num,Central_Node_Num,Tot_System_Delay,Bandwidth_Reqt\n");
    }

    // Writing Data
    fprintf(fp,"%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n",node_num,agg_num,cnode,sysdelay,bwdth_reqt);
}
```

For 100 simulations, the output I get from the debug shows me:

```
0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-
```

What am I doing wrong? I suspect that the program stores everything in a buffer and only prints everything to the file after it is done with the simulations and the files are closed.

Note: I open and close the files only once during the whole program and not for each simulation.

Comment: Try fflush(fp); at the end of your function.

Comment: You clearly open/close the file elsewhere, so why not write the headers when you open the file, and just check that `fp` is open here before writing the data? No need for a buffer flush and length check then.

Comment: @Emmet This is a good idea too. I'll try both yours as well as Ivarpoiss' idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. Stdio has it's own output buffering and fstat is only concerned with logical files. So the file writes do get delayed. Try putting `fflush(fp);` for the last line in your Data_Output function. I hope that helps.

Comment: I ended up sticking with Emmet's solution. Yours' works equally well though. Thanks for all the help!